# Yii LOGIN without the index.php it shows the login form again

Tags: php, authentication, yii

I have this problem in YII Once you log in you are redirected to index.php, but if you go to 
http://staging.xxxxxxxx.com/

without the index.php it shows the login form again.

I dont know what to do to make it go to index.php when logged in.. I hope someone could help me.. Im really new to yii

Comment: Do the cookies get deleted when visiting the root of the page (not index.php)?

Comment: @dave chen no i dont think so.. gosh im completely clueless.. 

i think though it needs an authentication where it will check if the user is logged in.. and if yes he will redirect it to the index.php and not in the login. though i dnt really know how.

Comment: Check your session cookies and once purge them all. From what I understand, you are trying to say that once you log in, you are still redirected to the login page is it?

Comment: It could be that your routing or .htaccess isn't set up properly. Read this http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url and http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/214/url-hide-index-php/

Comment: if you are redirected to a different domain, than the cookies are different too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if user logged in or not by use this code :

```
if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest){ // not logged in 

    $this->redirect(array('controller/action')); /// redirect to target page 
}
else{
   $this->redirect(array('controller/action')); /// redirect to target page 
}
```

Comment: thanks.. it worled i included it in the login method and just changed some codes from the previous that i have